# Office 365: Install selected packages

Tags: office365

Does anyone have a way to install only selected packages when installing office365. I only want Word, Excel and PowerPoint. Not all the other stuff that comes with it.
I've found a couple of way of doing it online, where you download the office deployment tool and have to manually create these configuration files and go through a bunch of shlep. This works on the installation. However, as soon as you launch any of the programs, it checks online and downloads the others anyway!

Comment: The Office deployment tool, more specifically the configuration file that is used, is the only method that allows you to customize which Office products are installed.  This has been the case for nearly 10 years (Office 2016 and newer).  Without specifics of the configuration file used it's difficult to answer this question.

Comment: Thnx - yes I gathered as much. In other words it no longer works.

Comment: The installation configuration file **absolutely works**, used it today, on the current version of Office 365 from this month. Care to give specifics?

Comment: I used the online tool (as the screen shots elsewhere in the thread) to create the configuration file. Then downloaded ODT files. Set the config in the terminal using VS Code. Then ran the setup via the config. It installed only the selected packages as I had selected. But then, when I opened Excel, the office updater launches and downloads the other packages in the background.

Comment: Post the configuration file minus the license key

Answer (score 1):

> > However, as soon as you launch any of the programs, it checks online and downloads the others anyway!

Generally, this situation is unexpected. It's best check your configuration file (.xml)

For Microsoft 365 Apps, if you want to customize the installation, you need the help of [ODT tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2fe0642e-4248-4175-94df-3e2a5bc09119) and configuration file (.xml).

In [Office Customization Tool](https://config.office.com/deploymentsettings) page, you can turn off the Office program that you do not need. Then follow the prompts to complete the settings and export the configuration file.

[image]

- And then put the .xml file and ODT tools in a folder.
- Run Command Prompt as administrator.
- Enter `cd` command to navigate to this folder.
- Continue to enter `setup.exe /configure` .xml file to install Office.

Comment: Thnx - yes I did this, but it doesnt work. as I stated in my question - as soon as you open any of the software packages, it updates and installs the others.